# single connection across all methods

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

In my project i am using jdbctemplate. currently in my project business layer calls different dao methods which executes the SQL queries and which results in could not get underlying db connection. 
in some module i have tried plain JDBC. and also tried the datasourcemanager and BasicDataSource
so what i want is get jdbctemplate obj in business layer and pass it on to all the dao methods. but in jdbctemplate every time i use a update methods its creating a new connection. how can i make single connection per thread.
thanks in advance

Comment: just create a Singleton to do this

Comment: i have created a map which will hold the data sources. while deploying the WAR datasource gets created and kept inside map. if map does not contain ds then new ds is created and kept inside it. and i get the connection using same data source

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of doing this is creating a singleton bean for each datasource and injecting the instance that Spring creates into any class that requires it. This ensures a single connection is made and used throughout the application.

Comment: can u provide me some documentation for it